# Alternatives for NHIbernate?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, orm, data-access-layer

HI all,

What all other libraries or frameworks we can use apart from NHIbernate?
Can linq work with entites as the NHIbernate does?
Can linq automatically generates entities for us?
Does the Data application block come with .NET 3.5 or some separate installation is required?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377236/nhibernate-entity-framework-active-records-or-linq2sql/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What all other libraries or frameworks we can use apart from NHIbernate?

[Subsonic Vs NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384/subsonic-vs-nhibernate)

> Can linq work with entites as the NHIbernate does?

No.

> Can linq automatically generates entities for us?

Yes.

> Does the Data application block come with .NET 3.5 or some separate installation is required?

No.